# How to add click event with window.error for js errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented `window.onerror=function(msg, fileurl, linenumber)` for js error logging but with this I can't get error source for click event.

Is there a way to get html tag(id or class) if the error is generated by clicking any html tag?

**I can not implement try catch because I have to add it in more than 30000 loc in more than 40 files**

ps:its not only click event but any event through which error is generated.

Comment: in the function there is a ajax call to php posting those 3 variables

Comment: ["Note that some/many error events do not trigger window.onerror, you have to listen for them specifically"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror).

Comment: My bad, its not only click but any event through which error is generating, because those errors are triggering window.onerror. eg onchange.